# fadeOut() only fades out the first element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

By default, I have several DIVs hidden and then I fade them in when the user clicks on a certain button. That works fine but when I try to close a .holder DIV using a span within said .holder DIV, only the first one works. When I click the others, nothing happens. I get no error or any sort of visual feedback whatsoever.

The markup:

```
<div class="holder" id="window_one">
    <div class="title_bar">
        <p>Window 1</p>
        <div class="control_holder">
            <span class="controls" id="close">X</span>
            <span class="controls" id="minimize">_</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="interface">
        <p>Testing123</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="calculator" id="window_two">
    <div class="title_bar">
        <p>Window 2</p>
        <div class="control_holder">
            <span class="controls" id="close">X</span>
            <span class="controls" id="minimize">_</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="interface">
        <p>Testing123</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

The jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#close').click(function() {
        $(this).parents('.holder').fadeOut(250);
    });
});
```

What exactly am I doing wrong here? I'm using jQuery 1.10.2 if that makes any difference.

I'd demo the code on jsFiddle but is seems to be down atm.

Comment: Ids should be unique, use classes

Comment: you can have multiple classes for one object, just separate them with space, i.e. class="class1 class2" this object can be addreses as .class1 or .class2....so use class instead of unique ids...and then dont forget that it will give you array so run through array and make it for every element >|

Comment: @M.Svrcek Oops, forgot about that, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can not have the same id of two element on the page. If you want to do that give it as a class name like -

```
<div class="holder" id="window_one">
    <div class="title_bar">
        <p>Window 1</p>
        <div class="control_holder">
            <span class="controls close">X</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="interface">
        <p>Testing123</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="calculator" id="window_two">
    <div class="title_bar">
        <p>Window 2</p>
        <div class="control_holder">
            <span class="controls close">X</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="interface">
        <p>Testing123</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the Jquery like -

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.close').click(function() {
        $(this).parents('.holder').fadeOut(250);
    });
});
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: Worked perfectly, thanks! Forgot about the multiple classes thing :P

Answer (score 0):

Here is how it should be:

```
<div class="holder" id="window_one">
    <div class="title_bar">
        <p>Window 1</p>
        <div class="control_holder">
            <span class="controls close">X</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="interface">
        <p>Testing123</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="calculator" id="window_two">
    <div class="title_bar">
        <p>Window 2</p>
        <div class="control_holder">
            <span class="controls close">X</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="interface">
        <p>Testing123</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.close').click(function(e) {

        $(this).parents('.holder').forEach(function(){

                  $(this).fadeOut(250);

                      });

         e.preventDefault();
    });

});
```